# Clicking Dropdown to get value with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I have input type text, when it clicked dropdown will be show. i've used a plugin from http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/ to show dropdown with data-dropdown . this my code :

```
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:100px; padding-bottom:12px;">Category</td>
                        <td>
        <input type="text" name="product" placeholder="Select category" maxlength="85" class="full text" data-dropdown="#dropdown-5"/>
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-heart line-icon icon-2"></span>
                            <div id="dropdown-5" class="dropdown dropdown-tip dropdown-anchor-right">
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dcategory">
                                    <li>Add Product</li>
                                    <li>Add Category</li>
                                    <li>Add Brand Information</li>
                                    <li>Add Note</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

i want to get a value from dropdown when it clicked and put it into input ??

is it possible ???

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible !

Try this with jQuery :

```
$("ul.dropdown-menu li").click(function(){
     this = $(this);
     inputval = this.text(); // sorry here it's text
     $("input.full").val(inputval);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
$('#dcategory li').click(function(){
     var x = $(this).text();
     $('input').val(x); //Give proper class 
})
```